Does there exist a projective module $P$ such that $P/rP$ is a simple module, yet $\pi: P \to P/rP$ fails to act as a projective cover map of $P/rP$?
If $P$ is a projective module over a semiperfect ring $R$ such that $P/rP$ is a simple module over $R$, then the canonical surjection $\pi: P \to P/rP$ must be a projective cover map of $P/rP$, where $r$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$. The following paragraph provides a detailed explanation.
When a projective cover of a simple module exists, it must be a finitely generated indecomposable projective module. Since $P/rP$ is a simple module over the semiperfect ring $R$, a projective cover of $P/rP$ exists, denoted by $Q$, and thus $Q$ is a finitely generated indecomposable projective module. Given that $P$ is a projective module and $\pi: P \to P/rP$ is surjective, $Q$ is a direct summand of $P$ because $Q$ serves as a projective cover of $P/rP$. As $P$ is projective and $P/rP$ is simple, $P$ is indecomposable and therefore isomorphic to $Q$. Consequently, $P$ is finitely generated because $Q$ is finitely generated. Since $P$ is finitely generated, $rP$ is the unique maximal superfluous submodule of $P$. As $rP$ is the kernel of $\pi: P \to P/rP$, and the kernel of the surjective map $\pi$ is a superfluous submodule of $P$, it follows that $\pi: P \to P/rP$ is a projective cover map, and $P$ is a projective cover of $P/rP$.
This raises the question:
What about non-semiperfect rings? That is, does there exist a projective module $P$ over a non-semiperfect ring such that $P/rP$ is a simple module, yet the canonical surjection $\pi: P \to P/rP$ fails to act as a projective cover map of $P/rP$?
Specifically, can we identify a proper submodule $L$ strictly contained within $P$ such that the sum of $L$ and $rP$ equals $P$?

Let $P$ be a projective $R$-module such that $P/rP=S$ is simple.
If $P$ is finitely-generated, then $P$ is always the projective cover of $S$. Every proper submodule of a finitely-generated module is contained in a maximal submodule, and $rP$ is the unique maximal submodule of $P$, so every proper submodule $L$ of $P$ is contained in $rP$, and so $rP+L\leq rP$.
If $P$ is not finitely generated, then it is never the projective cover of $S$. In fact, if $S$ has any projective cover $P_S$, then since $S$ is a quotient of $R$, $P_S$ is a direct summand of $R$, and so must be finitely-generated.
There remains the question of whether there are any infinitely-generated projective modules $P$ such that $P/rP$ is simple, and there are.
An example is given in A counterexample to two hypotheses on projective and flat modules by Gerasimov and Sakhaev (Siberian Math. Journal 25, 855-859 (1984)). Their goal was to show that there is an infinitely generated projective module $P$ such that $P/rP$ is finitely generated, which was an open problem, and it takes some work to extract from their paper the fact that $P/rP$ is actually simple, but this is made clearer in the later treatment in Projective modules over the Gerasimov-Sakhaev counterexample by Dubrovnin, Příhoda and Puninski (J.Algebra 319, 3259-3279 (2008)).

Thank you for your answer and analysis, as well as for providing detailed references, which have been very enlightening. Specifically, in the paper Projective modules over the Gerasimov-Sakhaev counterexample by Dubrovnin, Příhoda, and Puninski (J. Algebra 319, 3259-3279 (2008)), the authors state that the dimension of the infinitely-generated $P$ (that is, the vector counting the multiplicities of the two simple $R_Σ$-modules as composition factors of $P/\operatorname{Jac}(P))$ is $(1,0)$, so $P/\operatorname{Jac}(P)$ is simple.
